# Sharepoint 2013 testing in visual studio Update 1

Tags: sharepoint

A sharepoint application is to be released in 3 to 4 months. At the time of release the frequency of downloads for that application is pretty high. So I need to test whether that server or web service this application is provided by can bear that load or not. Now here is my question. For this I just have a WSDL file of the web service and nothing else. How should I test this by imposing a virtual load of about 20000 users in visual studio 2012 update 1. The application was developed in sharepoint 2013.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For Web service load test I suggest [SOAP UI](http://www.soapui.org/pages/index2/index2.html?utm_expid=56905-16.GqCorYDvTiKdagQSSeoWNw.1&utm_referrer=http://www.soapui.org/pages/index2/index2.html). It is open source (look for soapUI not soapUI pro) and extremely easy to use.
You can create the tests and the load / stress tests against the wsdl and execute them once the implementation is there.